# Grouping multiple generic parameters for easy access

Tags: java, generics

I have a complex circular generic structure:

```
interface Job<J extends Job<J,R,E>, R extends Recipient<J,R,E>, E extends Event<J,R,E>> { }
interface Recipient<J extends Job<J,R,E>, R extends Recipient<J,R,E>, E extends Event<J,R,E> { }
interface Event<J extends Job<J,R,E>, R extends Recipient<J,R,E>, E extends Event<J,R,E> { }
```

This design is the result of trimming copy paste code. It is type-safe by this way but very hard to use:

```
class EmailJob implements Job<EmailJob, EmailRecipient, EmailEvent> { }
class VoiceCallJob implements Job<VoiceCallJob, VoiceCallRecipient, VoiceCallEvent> { }
//Recipient and Event classes omitted.
```

Below is a sample, job independent class:

```
class LoadBalanceProcessor<J extends Job<J,R,E>, R extends Recipient<J,R,E>, E extends Event<J,R,E>> {
    @Inject
    Provider<JobDao<J extends Job<J,R,E>, R extends Recipient<J,R,E>, E extends Event<J,R,E>>> jobDaoProvider;
    long getTimeToWait(J job, R recipient){...}
}
```

What I wish is to -somehow- group those 3 generic parameters in one, and declare them easily:

```
class LoadBalanceProcessor<JobTypeGroup>{
    @Inject
    Provider<JobDao<JobTypeGroup>> jobDaoProvider;
    long getTimeToWait(/* ?? */) {...}
}
```

How can I declare something like the JobTypeGroup parameter pointing the Job-Recipient-Event triplet? I can change the original job declarations.

Comment: This seems to me as more of a design question than generics question. How about creating JobTypeGroup as a class and tweaking around it?

Comment: Try creating Abstract class for Job, Recipient and Event and use those or the interfaces in other classes. It would give you flexibility.